# "der" for feminine noun

Tags: grammaticality

I have a doubt regarding this sentence

> Er flirtet mit der Kellnerin

Well from what I have learnt so far "der" is used for masculine noun however in the above mentioned sentence "der" is being used for "Kellnerin" which is a feminine noun. Can somebody explain to me why it's happening ?

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate, but I don’t think that it is great to close something as a duplicate of a closed question. I have voted to reopen the other question so that we can use it to direct other questions to that one.

Comment: @Carsten S: I agree that referring to another closed question isn't good form, but the reason the previous question was closed applies here too. An explanation of the dative case and a declination table for *der* can be found in any textbook on German. Perhaps [this link](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/Nouns/dative.html) would be more helpful to the OP, especially the section on prepositions.

Comment: @RDBury, all true, but I think it wouldn’t hurt to have one of these questions, even if the answer is just, hey, German has cases! (And the case/gender table for definite articles is weird.)

Comment: The rationale for closing duplicate questions is not to answer the same questions over and over. Maybe some people on German SE don't mind answering the same questions again, but closing duplicates seems to be a rule of SE in general, not only of German SE.

Comment: I **agree** that this is a duplicate. I have voted to reopen the **other** question so that we can use it to direct other questions to that one.

Comment: @user4x: Welcome. German has cases for nouns, like nominative, genitive, dative, accussative (and a few historical ones that play no role in modern German). Soon you'll find out that "mit jemandem flirten" requires a dative. In the beginning, you'll need declension tables, for instance http://germanforenglishspeakers.com/reference/complete-declension-tables/.